# Ignore lines starting with '//' and empty lines in yaml code

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, scripting, yaml

I'm trying to read all lines in a .txt file except the lines starting with two forward slashes '//' and empty lines using lookup in my yaml code, this is what my code looks like:

```
---
- name: playbook for API release deployment
  hosts: api
  become: yes
  ignore_errors: true
  vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: deploy-api | upgrade Addons using loop
      command: "{{ module_install }} -u {{ item }} --stop-after-init"
      args:
        chdir: /opt/app/
      with_items:
        - "{{ lookup('file', 'addons.txt') | grep -v '^(//)' }}"
```

This is what the .txt file looks like:

```
// Comment 1
// Commment 2
// Comment 3

// Comment 4

addons 1
addons 2
addons 3
```

Ansible throws me an error:

fatal: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'. String: {{ lookup('file', 'addons.txt') | grep -v '^(//)' }}"}

I'm not sure on how to do this, how should I escape those lines starting with '//' and empty lines?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider rethinking your code. Instead of `addons.txt` just use a proper Ansible array variable.

```
// inventory/all/all.yml
# comment
addons:
  - addons 1
  - addons 2
  - addons 3

// playbook.yml
      with_items: '{{ addons }}'
```

Anyway, untested, something like the following can make you started:

```
with_items: "{{
   lookup('file', 'addons.txt').splitlines() |
   reject('match', '^//') |
   join('\n')
   }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"How should I escape lines starting with '//' and empty lines?"***

A: [*reject*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.reject) matching lines. See [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings). For example,

```yaml
  lines: "{{ lookup('file', 'addons.txt').splitlines()|
             reject('regex', '^//')|
             reject('regex', '^$') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  lines:
  - addons 1
  - addons 2
  - addons 3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    module_install: install
    lines: "{{ lookup('file', 'addons.txt').splitlines()|
               reject('regex', '^//')|
               reject('regex', '^$') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: lines

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ module_install }} -u {{ item }} --stop-after-init"
      loop: "{{ lines }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  lines:
  - addons 1
  - addons 2
  - addons 3

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=addons 1) => 
  msg: install -u addons 1 --stop-after-init
ok: [localhost] => (item=addons 2) => 
  msg: install -u addons 2 --stop-after-init
ok: [localhost] => (item=addons 3) => 
  msg: install -u addons 3 --stop-after-init

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```